# How to structure php if statement to check for smartquote

Tags: php

In a db returned record, the var $bookTitle either starts with a smartquote or does not.  If the first character is a smartquote, I want to display the record as-is.  If the first character is anything else (letter or number), I want the concatenated string to be italicized.  I've tried a couple different ways to structure the == '"' without success.  The current version is italicized, no matter what is returned (NOTE: the code pasted here won't correctly depict smartquotes).

EDIT: The only part of the statement not working is the ($titleFormat == '"').

EDIT:  I discovered that running echo $titleFormat returns a black diamond with a question mark.

```
<?php 
    $titleFormat = $bookTitle[0];
    if ($titleFormat == '"') {
      echo $Parsedown->text($bookTitle . ' ' . $bookSubtitle); 
    }
    else { ?>
    <em><?php echo $Parsedown->text($bookTitle . ' ' . $bookSubtitle); ?></em>
    
    <?php 
    } ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "smartquote"? Also, what **exactly** is not working with the given code? Can you share sample input, and the expected output?

Comment: Smartquote is another name for curly quote, used in typography.

Comment: If the $bookTitle is stored in the db as "The Best Western", then the if statement logic should pick up that the first character is the curly/smartquote and not italicize the output.  If there is not a curly/smartquote, then italicize the output.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question**  by editing. Also, explain which parts of your code are working, and which are not, along with the steps you've took to check **why** something is not working as expected

Comment: Also, if the code pasted here does not match the code you are using, what's the diffference?

Comment: Because Stack Overflow's editor changes smart/curly quotes to straight quotes.

Comment: `EDIT: The only part of the statement not working is the ($titleFormat == '"').` - what does that mean? How could an `if` statement not work? What does `$titleFormat` contain in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking with regex...

```php
if ( preg_match( '/^"|^“/', $bookTitle ) ) {
  echo $Parsedown->text( $bookTitle . ' ' . $bookSubtitle );
} else {
  printf( '<em>%s</em>', $Parsedown->text( $bookTitle . ' ' . $bookSubtitle ) );
}
```

Have you also considered that the db result might be encoded, for example: `&quot;`?

Could it be that the character isn't actually `"` but `“` instead? I've updated the regex above.

Comment: Data is stored in MariaDB, utf8mb4_unicode_gi